# Electron & ReactJS, Use BrowserWindow for GitHub oAuth authentication

Tags: oauth, callback, github-api, electron

I have set up github's Electron with ReactJs. So I got a `BrowserWindow` and a react app playing nicely in that window. What I'm trying to achieve is to get authenticated with GitHub. So when a user presses the `Login with Github` button, a new `BrowserWindow` opens and goes to the github authorize app url. The issue I have has to do with the **callback** and how I will get the code returned from the callback. I've done it with Apache Cordova and the `InAppBrowser` but it was different since I was able to use `localhost` as a callback.

What I've done so far with electron is opening the new `BrowserWindow` but after the authorization I cannot get the code from the callback.

```js
var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: true, 'always-on-top': true });
var githubUrl = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?';
var authUrl = githubUrl + 'client_id=' + options.client_id + '&scope=' + options.scope;

authWindow.loadUrl(authUrl);
authWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);
authWindow.setResizable(false);

authWindow.addListener('page-title-updated', function(stream) {
  console.log("LOADED");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(stream));
  console.log(stream);

  var url = (typeof stream.url !== 'undefined' ? stream.url : stream.originalEvent.url),
    raw_code = /code=([^&]*)/.exec(stream.url) || null,
    code = (raw_code && raw_code.length > 1) ? raw_code[1] : null,
    error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(strean.url);

  if (code || error) {
    authWindow.close();
  }

  // If there is a code in the callback, proceed to get token from github
  if (code) {
    // requestToken(code);
  } else if (error) {
    alert("Oops! Couldn't log authenticate you with using Github.");
  }
});
```

Where I'm doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(stream));` I get `{}` so it's something that has to do the the `eventListener`? Any ideas or better approaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what I was missing was the right `event`. The correct approach is:

```js
// Build the OAuth consent page URL
var authWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: false, 'node-integration': false });
var githubUrl = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?';
var authUrl = githubUrl + 'client_id=' + options.client_id + '&scope=' + options.scopes;
authWindow.loadUrl(authUrl);
authWindow.show();

// Handle the response from GitHub
authWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request', function(event, oldUrl, newUrl) {

  var raw_code = /code=([^&]*)/.exec(newUrl) || null,
    code = (raw_code && raw_code.length > 1) ? raw_code[1] : null,
    error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(newUrl);

  if (code || error) {
    // Close the browser if code found or error
    authWindow.close();
  }

  // If there is a code in the callback, proceed to get token from github
  if (code) {
    requestGithubToken(options, code);
  } else if (error) {
    alert("Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't log you in using Github. Please try again.");
  }

});

// Reset the authWindow on close
authWindow.on('close', function() {
    authWindow = null;
}, false);
```

I also wrote a tutorial that describes the full implementation which can be found at http://manos.im/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/

Comment: Thanks man, saved me lots of hours. However, is it safe to hardcode the client secret in the source code? After all, everyone can inspect the client's source code.