# Electron + Angular (7) OAuth 2.0 Redirect

Tags: angular, oauth, oauth-2.0, electron

I am using the the AppAuth-JS library to do help with doing and Auth Code Flow + PKCE in my Electron + Angular (7) project based off [this seed](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron). After building the built package and trying to launch the app all my redirects back to local host keep failing.

When running the app in development mode using (npm start) the auth flow works fine because electron uses ng serve and the whole auth flow works correctly. After I package the electron app and then try to launch it and login then it seems like the redirections to localhost are failing...

I think this is due to the fact that when the app is run by opening index.html from the built dist folder... So there is nothing handling the calls to local host.

After searching around everyone seems to say you should be able to redirect back to localhost... and I have seen in done in apps that use the same method of opening index.html directly from the build dir... So I am not sure why it doesn't work for me. But also all these apps always redirect to just the root of localhost... I want to be able to redirect back to something like localhost/login.

P.S

2 solutions I was thinking I can do are:

1. Using a separate window to launch the request to the auth server + webcontents to catch the redirect and pull the scope out as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584287/5748651)
2. Instead of launching the app straight from index.html... Start up some kind of node server will redirect all calls (/*) back to index.html... The problem with this is... I am not sure how to pass the routes like /login down to index.html... I heard u can include a hash after the _dir/index.html path but I am not to familiar with it.

Thanks everyone.